# C++ Getting "Debug Error R6010 -abort() has been called " when i assign promises to threads

Tags: c++, multithreading, promise, future

i'm getting error:[Debug Error R6010 -abort() has been called](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Up067.png)

in my code :

```
bool ListFiles(wstring path, wstring mask, vector<wstring>& files) {
HANDLE hFind = INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE;
WIN32_FIND_DATA ffd;
wstring spec;
stack<wstring> directories;

directories.push(path);
files.clear();

while (!directories.empty()) {
    path = directories.top();
    spec = path + L"\\" + mask;
    directories.pop();

    hFind = FindFirstFile(spec.c_str(), &ffd);
    if (hFind == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)  {
        return false;
    }

    do {
        if (wcscmp(ffd.cFileName, L".") != 0 && wcscmp(ffd.cFileName, L"..") != 0) {
            if (ffd.dwFileAttributes & FILE_ATTRIBUTE_DIRECTORY) {
                directories.push(path + L"/" + ffd.cFileName);
            }
            else {
                files.push_back(path + L"/" + ffd.cFileName);
            }
        }
    } while (FindNextFile(hFind, &ffd) != 0);

    if (GetLastError() != ERROR_NO_MORE_FILES) {
        FindClose(hFind);
        return false;
    }

    FindClose(hFind);
    hFind = INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE;
}

return true;}

void findText(std::string filename, std::string word , promise<string> &prom) {
std::ifstream f(filename);
std::string s;
std::string notFound = "no";
bool found = false;
if (!f) {
    std::cout << "il file non esiste"<<std::endl;
}
while (f.good()) {
        std::getline(f, s);
        if (s.find(word, 0) != string::npos) {
            found = true;
        }

    }
if (found) {

    //cout << "Parola trovata in -> " << filename << endl;
    prom.set_value_at_thread_exit(filename);
}
else {
    prom.set_value_at_thread_exit(notFound);
}

f.close();}
int main(int argc, char* argv[]){
//vector<std::thread> th;
vector<future<string>> futures;
vector<wstring> files;
string search = "ciao";
string notFound = "no";
if (ListFiles(L"pds", L"*", files)) {

    for (vector<wstring>::iterator it = files.begin(); it != files.end(); ++it) {
        //wcout << it->c_str() << endl;
        wstring ws(it->c_str());
        string str(ws.begin(), ws.end());
        // Show String
        //cout << str << endl;
        //Creo una promise per ogni thread in cui andrò a cercare il risulato
        std::promise<string> prom;
        futures.push_back(prom.get_future());
        std::thread(findText,str,search,std::ref(prom)).detach();

    }
}   

for (int i = 0; i < futures.size(); i++){
    futures.at(i).wait();
    if (futures.at(i).get().compare(notFound)!=0)
    cout << "Parola trovata in ->" <<futures.at(i).get()<<endl;
}
return 0;}
```

I've tried before without using promises and making each thread printing the name of file if word was found and it worked.
So i don't know why using promises and future to retrive this value cause me this problem...
I'm using VS 2013

Comment: Have you tried to run in a debugger to locate exactly where in your code it happens? Can you at least point out the line in the code you show where it happens, with a comment (in English) for example?

Comment: using debug i recive this 2 errors: _Unhandled exception at 0x7545C41F in std_Thread.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: std::future_error at memory location 0x003AF700._ and  _Run-Time Check Failure #0 - The value of ESP was not properly saved across a function call.  This is usually a result of calling a function declared with one calling convention with a function pointer declared with a different calling convention._ The problem must be in the main function when i create the promises and i assign it to the thread.

Comment: If you run in a debugger, the program will stop when you get the `abort`. Then you will be able to go up the function call stack to your code, and see *exactly* where in your code it happens.

Comment: i just added a try{} catch{} block in the last for cycle and it throws and exception: "broken promise"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Lets take a close look at these lines lines:

```
for (...) {
    ...
    std::promise<string> prom;
    ...
    std::thread(findText,str,search,std::ref(prom)).detach();
}
```

First you create a local variable `prom`, and then you pass a reference to that variable to the thread.

The problem with this is that once the loop iterates, the variable `prom` goes out of scope and the object is destructed. The reference you once had no longer have anything it references. Using the reference will lead to *undefined behavior*.

So the solution is to not use references (or pointers to the `prom` variable), which leads to problems because [`std::promise`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/promise) can't be copied. It can, however, be moved:

```
std::thread(findText,str,search,std::move(prom)).detach();
```

Fir this you might need to make the thread function take the promise argument as a rvalue reference:

```
void findText(std::string filename, std::string word , promise<string> &&prom) {
    ...
}
```

---

If the above solution doesn't work, then you could use dynamic allocation using the new C++11 smart pointers like [`std::unique_ptr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr).

Then the thread function should take the smart pointer by value, like

```
void findText(std::string filename, std::string word , std::unique_ptr<std::promise<string>> prom) {
    ...
}
```

And you create the thread like

```
auto prom = std::make_unique<std::promise<std::string>>();
// Or if you don't have std::make_unique
//   std::unique_ptr<std::promise<std::string>> prom(new std::promise<std::string>);
futures.push_back(prom->get_future();
std::thread(findText,str,search,std::move(prom)).detach();
```

Remember that in your thread function (`findText`) the variable `prom` is a *pointer* and you need to use the arrow operator when using it, like e.g.

```
prom->set_value_at_thread_exit(filename);
//  ^^
// Note "arrow" operator here
```

Comment: And how can solve this problem and keep trace of promises?

Comment: Wasn't the last line the answer to your question?

Comment: Modifying this i obtain: ...Threads have exited with code 3 (0x3).

Comment: Using your answer std::move(prom), i have to modify the function findText taking (promise<string> prom) instead of (promise<string> &prom) but then i have this error  _Error 2 error C2280: 'std::promise<std::string>::promise(const std::promise<std::string> &)' : attempting to reference a deleted function c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 12.0\vc\include\functional 1149 1 std_Thread_

Comment: @A.Martino Change the thread function to take the promise as a rvalue reference (i.e. `std::promise<std::string>&& prom`).

Comment: @JoachimPileborg i'm getting crazy, doing this i recive the error: _Error 1 error C2664: 'void (std::string,std::string,std::promise<std::string> &&)' : cannot convert argument 3 from 'std::promise<std::string>' to 'std::promise<std::string> &&' c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 12.0\vc\include\functional 1149 1 std_Thread_

Comment: @A.Martino Then allocate the promise dynamically, using e.g. `std::unique_ptr`? The thread function should be able to take the `std::unique_ptr` by value, but you must still use `std::move` when creating the thread.

Comment: @A.Martino VS2013 didn't have very good C++11 support,it's much better in the 2015 edition, but it's not fully there yet.